# Angular directive controller: Argument is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a directive inside my controller, which i want to include another controller to the directive. The error i get back is `Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'js/controllers/testview/DocumentController.js' is not a function, got undefined`

**TestviewController**

```
app.controller('TestviewController', ['$http', '$scope', '$sessionStorage', '$state', '$log', 'Session', 'api', function ($http, $scope, $sessionStorage, $state, $log, Session, api) {
    var module_id = $state.params.id;

    $http.get(api.getUrl('componentsByModule', module_id))
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.components = response;
        });
}]);

app.directive('viewDoc', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: "tpl/directives/testview/document.html",
        controller: "js/controllers/testview/DocumentController.js",
        resolve: { components: function() { return $scope.components }}
    };
});
```

**DocumentController**

```
app.controller('DocumentController', ['$http', '$scope', '$sessionStorage', '$state', '$log', 'Session', 'api', 'components', function ($http, $scope, $sessionStorage, $state, $log, Session, api, components) {
    $scope.components = components;
}]);
```

I'm pretty new  with directices, but does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In that case controller is not a js file, it's actually controller name in scope of app i.e. `controller: "TestviewController"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the directive definition object, the `controller` property expects a string with the function name, or the function itself (not the path to script file).

```
app.directive('viewDoc', function () {
    return {
        ...
        controller: "DocumentController",

    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to call the controller by name, not by file name:

```
controller: "js/controllers/testview/DocumentController.js"
```

should be

```
controller: "DocumentController"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to put controller by its URL in the directive definition. However if you define your controller in DOM template you could use `controller: 'myController as myCtrl'` in directive definition

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you need a directive controller? i think what you are trying to achieve is link function.

you can use directive link functions like controllers.

```
.directive('myDialog', function() {
  return {
   restrict: 'E',
transclude: true,
scope: {},
templateUrl: 'my-dialog.html',
link: function (scope, element) {
  scope.name = 'Jeff';
}
  };
});
```

take a look at angular docs
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive